# Can you open gallery when camera app is open to get images in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I'm working on an native android application in Java. I have already implemented camera functionalities that upload images to firebase storage when captured, but I expected that you could also open your gallery from the camera and upload those images like facebook messenger. Until now I have only found tutorials that separate camera and gallery with a menu that appears by clicking an [add button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xePbK.png).

[Where gallery should normally be located in the camera application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKxLm.png)

Comment: One does not open the gallery from camera. One just opens the gallery and pick a file.

Comment: But how is facebook messenger doing it than?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook messenger is implementing their own gallery, reading files probably from MediaStore.

If you want to open the gallery from your app and pick a picture you should launch an intent:

```
private val pickImageFromGallery = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { 
  uri: Uri? ->
    uri?.let { 
      // handle the data here
    }
}
```

Then launch the intent from a button click or something else:

```
pickImageFromGallery.launch("image/*")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.